# Can not download docx file using SharePoint file download REST API & Java

Tags: java, sharepoint

I got the attached img value as response from the SharePoint server but can not write it on the docx file. The file download API using Postman is giving same response and if I save Postman response to docx file then it is saving perfectly but not from Java side. If I write same response to a docx file using Java, the file is corrupted.

I am using this REST API to download the file from Sharepoint:

```
SiteURL/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('relativeURL/Shared Documents/test.docx')/$value
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you're populating responseStrFromSharePoint?

Comment: As a precaution, set breakpoint at `String responseStrFromSharePoint = response.getBody();` and debug to check if response body indeed contains the legitimate document.

Comment: Yes, response body is giving correct response from SP server, I cross matched  my Java code response with the Postman's response. Problem is when converting it to a file.

Comment: Then most likely it is due to the _encoding_ while writing the body to file. Instead of writing the string representation of the response (`ResponseEntity<String>`), you should writing the exact binary (bytes) returned by server.

Comment: Using `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` instead of `ResponseEntity<String>` should do. That way `response.getBody()` returns `byte[]` instead of `String`. Write that to file as you are doing now.

Comment: OK, I will check and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely server is returning the document (docx) as binary (`application/octet-stream`). Your code saves the document's string representation:

```java
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(fileUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
        String responseStrFromSharePoint = response.getBody();
```

That's why the file could not be decoded by application. Instead save the exact binary (bytes) returned by the server as the following snippet shows:

```java
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(fileUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, byte[].class);
        byte[] responseStrFromSharePoint = response.getBody();
```

Other parts of the code seems fine.